# Refresh layout when get push notification

Tags: android

How can I refresh layout when get push notification? 
I get class:

```
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                // Post notification of received message.
                message = extras.getString("message");
                badgeCount = extras.getString("badge");
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        mNotificationManager  = (NotificationManager)getApplication().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageActivity.class);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icons)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(message))
                .setContentText(message).setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

        try {
            if(Integer.parseInt(badgeCount) != 0)
                ShortcutBadger.setBadge(getApplicationContext(), Integer.parseInt(badgeCount));
        } catch (ShortcutBadgeException e) {
            //handle the Exception
        }


    }

}
```

where I receive push  notification. So, when I am in first activity and get push notification I want to refresh all this activity. This should work with 3 activities, so when I am in second activity and get push so this second activity should recreate. Any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make user of [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

**ReceiverActivity.java**

An activity that watches for notifications for the event named "custom-event-name".

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  // Register to receive messages.
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
  // with actions named "custom-event-name".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

**SenderActivity.java**

The second activity that sends/broadcasts notifications.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  // Every time a button is clicked, we want to broadcast a notification.
  findViewById(R.id.button_send).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      sendMessage();
    }
  });
}

// Send an Intent with an action named "custom-event-name". The Intent sent should 
// be received by the ReceiverActivity.
private void sendMessage() {
  Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

You can send message(SecondActivity.java) from the `onMessage` method of your notification receiver.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is perfect for me.